# How to use sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h in eclipse C/C++ project

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, sqlite, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to use amalgamated version of sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h in my C/C++ project. It has code in both C and C++. I am using eclipse IDE in UBUNTU 12.04.

Now my problem is that after having include sqlite3.h in my file where I need sqlite3.c functions and having added ld and pthread libraries in linker, i am still getting errors and cant build the project.

This is weird and should not happen. Please take a look at following screenshots that explain my problem.

### [image: Snapshot of project]

### ************************************************************************************

### [image: Errors Snapshot]

### ************************************************************************************

[image: Snapshot of included libs]

What am I missing?

Please Help!
Thanks

Comment: Can't see the screenshots.

Comment: @ScoPi - Sounds like a personal problem... I can see them.

Comment: My network blocks where he's hosting the images. Just copy and paste your errors, VinayChoudhary99.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the *pthread* library is linked *before* the *dl* library.

In other words, your compiler command (as generated by Eclipse) should be:

gcc shell.c sqlite3.c -lpthread -ldl

and not

gcc shell.c sqlite3.c -ldl -lpthread

See here for a correct command line:

http://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html

Comment: Hi I just need sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h files. Also as i am using eclipse for building, how do i make sure that some files are build using certain libs?

Comment: @VinayChoudhary99: for the time being, just add the dl and pthread kibrary to Eclipse in INVERSE ORDER than you did.