# Sqlite3.c query execution and database closing error in C, C++ project in eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, sqlite, eclipse-cdt

I am using eclipse in ubunt 12.04 in my C/C++ project and I am getting following error when trying to execute a query. 
I have posted the stack as well as query to execute and syntax:

*this one succeeds always*

Query 1:CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HS_TABLE (user TEXT NOT NULL, passwd TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(user) );

*this query succeeds first time but fails second time*

Query 2: INSERT OR REPLACE INTO HS_TABLE (user, passwd) SELECT 'user 0','passwd 0' UNION SELECT 'user 1','passwd 1' UNION SELECT 'user 2','passwd 2';

Thread [1] 5556 [core: 3] (Suspended : Signal : **SIGSEGV**:Segmentation fault)

```
sqlite3Init() at sqlite3.c:93,817 0x466540  
sqlite3ReadSchema() at sqlite3.c:93,855 0x466667    
sqlite3LocateTable() at sqlite3.c:81,026 0x4506f9   
sqlite3LocateTableItem() at sqlite3.c:81,065 0x45081f   
sqlite3SrcListLookup() at sqlite3.c:85,104 0x457c79 
sqlite3Insert() at sqlite3.c:89,190 0x45e612    
yy_reduce() at sqlite3.c:1,10,576 0x4822d2  
sqlite3Parser() at sqlite3.c:1,11,347 0x484a5d  
sqlite3RunParser() at sqlite3.c:1,12,172 0x4856fc   
sqlite3Prepare() at sqlite3.c:94,032 0x466a48
sqlite3LockAndPrepare() at sqlite3.c:94,124 0x466d77
sqlite3_prepare_v2 at sqlite3.c:94,200 0x466f2e
```

*Also I sqlite3_close(sqlite3* db) function fails and program terminates every time*

Thread [1] 5845 [core: 0] (Suspended : Signal : SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault)

```
sqlite3MemSize() at sqlite3.c:15,594 0x406d41   
sqlite3MallocSize() at sqlite3.c:19,021 0x407a73    
sqlite3_free() at sqlite3.c:19,044 0x407afd 
sqlite3DbFree() at sqlite3.c:19,080 0x407c16    
sqliteDeleteColumnNames() at sqlite3.c:81,237 0x450da7  
sqlite3DeleteTable() at sqlite3.c:81,296 0x450f0e   
sqlite3SchemaClear() at sqlite3.c:85,035 0x457b23   
sqlite3LeaveMutexAndCloseZombie() at sqlite3.c:1,13,533 0x487682    
sqlite3Close() at sqlite3.c:1,13,473 0x487558   
sqlite3_close() at sqlite3.c:1,13,486 0x48757c
```

CODE:

```
sql_ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(m_database, CurrQuery, -1, &stmt, NULL);
```

Is there any error in my query, If so why is it crashing, this happened when i tried to debug in EClipse.

Here is the code:

```
ErrorCode DBResponder::openDB(const char* DBPath)
{
UINT64 sql_ret;

sql_ret = sqlite3_open(DBPath,&m_database);
cout<<__func__<<": sql_ret = "<<sql_ret<<endl;
if(  sql_ret != SQLITE_OK )
    return DB_ERROR;

return NO_ERROR;
}

ErrorCode DBResponder::closeDB()
{ 
UINT64 sql_ret;

sql_ret = sqlite3_close(m_database);
cout<<__func__<<": sql_ret = "<<sql_ret<<endl;
if( sql_ret != SQLITE_OK )
    return DB_ERROR;

return NO_ERROR;
}

ErrorCode DBResponder::executeQuery()
{
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
UINT64 sql_ret;
const char *CurrQuery = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO HS_TABLE (user, passwd) SELECT 'user 0','passwd 0' UNION SELECT 'user 1','passwd 1' UNION SELECT 'user 2','passwd 2';";

ErrorCode err = NO_ERROR;

cout<<endl<<__func__<<": "<<CurrQuery<<endl;
sql_ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(m_database, CurrQuery, -1, &stmt, NULL);
cout<<__func__<<": sql_ret (sqlite3_prepare_v2) = "<<sql_ret<<endl;
if(sql_ret != SQLITE_OK)
    return DB_ERROR;

HInfo* h;

while(1)
{
    sql_ret = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    cout<<__func__<<": sql_ret (sqlite3_step) = "<<sql_ret<<endl;
    if(sql_ret == SQLITE_ROW)
    {

        hs = (HInfo*)malloc(1*sizeof(HInfo));

        strncpy(hs->user, (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt,0), MAX_STR_LEN );
        strncpy(hs->passwd, (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt,1), MAX_STR_LEN);

        llist.add( (void*) hs);

    }
    else if(sql_ret == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        //query finished
        //return hs;
        writeResponse(hs);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        //error
        err = DB_ERROR;
        writeResponse(NULL);
        break;
    }
}//end of while loop

sql_ret = sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
cout<<__func__<<": sql_ret (sqlite3_finalize) = "<<sql_ret<<endl;
if(sql_ret != SQLITE_OK)
    err = DB_ERROR;

return err;
}
```

ALSO I am getting error : 
*Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
int sqlite3_open(const char *, * *)
'*

like this for every sqlite3 function. Note the * *, instead of sqlite3**, But the project is getting built. I have include dl and pthread in linker. Please see this for error:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859956/how-to-use-sqlite3-c-and-sqlite3-h-in-eclipse-c-c-project

Kindly help!
Thanks

Comment: If you run your program in a debugger, it will tell you where the crash happens, it will let you step up and down the call stack, and it will let you examine variables. All to help you figure out where and why the crash happened.

Comment: Besides that, there isn't anything wrong with the single line you posted. You have to give us more context, in other words please add the surrounding code, especially the declarations and initializations of `CurrQuery` and `stmt`.

Comment: I have edited and posted the code